# How do I install pip on Python 3.8.10?

Tags: python, windows, pip

So, I've got a problem - when I tried to use mtkclient, the manual said to use

```
python -m pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

command, and when I tried it, cmd gave me an error saying there's no such module named 'pip', but I literally reinstalled python right now! What do I do?

I tried 'ensurepip', but it gave me a long WinError 2.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Have you tried just `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` or even `pip install -r requirements.txt`, without `python -m` ?

Comment: StonedTensor, when I tried just pip without python -m, it said there's no such program named pip

Comment: `python -m mod …` means *run library module `mod` as a script*. I doubt that there is a module `pip3`; try `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`…